# Is there a pattern for extending a base class with children that implements an interface?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Lets say I have 2 classes that implements the same interface:

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Child1
{
    private const int CONST1 = 0;

    void IDoSomething.DoSomehting()
    { /*Do something the way a Child1 would*/ }
}

public class Child2
{
    private const int CONST1 = 0;

    void IDoSomething.DoSomehting()
    { /*Do something the way a Child2 would*/ }
}
```

What I want to know is since both class uses the same constant (`CONST1`) should I create a new class something like:

```
public class Parent
{
    private const int CONST1 = 0;
}
```

and then make `Child1` and `Child2` inherit from that class assuming that the real classes in this scenario is bigger (has more then one constant and more than one function implemented through the interface)?

Comment: You can declare the parent class as abstract, then mark the constant as protected. Then you can mark the interface method in the parent class as abstract, forcing the child class to implement it.

Comment: You don't need to inherit from a class to use a constant.   You can access a constant from another, unrelated, class, so long as it's public.

Comment: @willaien your comment seems to make a lot of sense

Comment: @Servy I know I can access if it is public but I can't have a direct reference to the other child like this, and onto which child should I put the constant? then anyone who would want to use the const needs to know where I put it? What if this constant is used internally by the two children, then I shouldn't be forced to make it public.

Comment: You can have both children implement the interface or you can have the parent be abstract and implement it--But I really just wanted to mention that you are possibly falling into a pitfall I did quite a few years ago.  Although it's good to learn about/understand these issues, I recommend you avoid inheritance unless it's painfully obvious you need it.  The commonly used phrase is "Prefer composition over inheritance".

Comment: @Sebastien It doesn't have to be on *either*, it could be somewhere else entirely.  If the value is *conceptually* different, then you *shouldn't* be looking to use the same identifier for both.  If it *is* conceptually the same value, then find a place that can house it for anything that might ever need it.

Comment: @Servy It is the same value for both, they represent the same thing in both children. Then I guess that if I am to mix your comment with Bill K's comment I should probably create a class housing these constant and inject it into the children (that would be avoiding inheritance and in favor of composition)?

Comment: @Sebastien You don't need to inject a class at all.  It's a constant.  Anyone can reference it at any time, from anywhere, in any context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance - NO.

> Inheritance is a good choice when:
>
> - Your inheritance hierarchy represents an "is-a" relationship and not a "has-a" relationship.
> - You can reuse code from the base classes.
> - ...

Source - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27db6csx(v=vs.90).aspx

Condition #1 fails immediately in your case because your child class "has-a" constant.

Condition #2 might have made you think of `Parent` but remember #1 should still be the priority when deciding to go for inheritance. Reuse code in #2 refers to reusing the behavior of parent class not just fields.

I think the comments on your post have already put you on a right track. I will just consolidate here.

```
public interface IDoSomething {
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Constants {
    private Constants() {}
    public const int CONST1 = 0;
}

public class Class1 : IDoSomething {
    public void DoSomething() { 
        Console.Write(Constants.CONST1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aaaaaahhhh, was that what Servy was trying to make me figure out in the comment on top?

Comment: Yes! That's correct.